# How to make WordPress work exclusively with WPGraphQl and block all the other routes?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wp-graphql

I am using WordPress exclusively as a backoffice for my Next-js app.
I only need 3 endpoints:

- `https://mydomain/graphql/*`
- `https://mydomain/wp-admin/*`
- `https://mydomain/wp-content/*`

I don't want to have anything else accessible. Is it somthing I should configure in the HTACCESS file or should I use a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially do something like the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file to block all URLs, except for those that start `/graphql/`, `/wp-admin/` or `/wp-content/`.

For example, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^(graphql|wp-admin|wp-content)/ - [F]
```

If anything else is requested then a 403 Forbidden is served.

However, I suspect there will be other URLs/files that still need to be accessible for this to work?

Comment: You answered my question but in the end I just allow my IP to connect to every route of my WP instance, then I generate the static content and deploy it. That was my original objective.